# Hailstone in Python

Tags: python

So I have this code that calculates the Hailstone sequence and keeps doing so 5 iterations. So if I input the number 128 I should get 64, 32, 16, 8, 4. I ultimately do, but not without it showing the list adding one number at a time at the end of the list. I would like to get the entire list and nothing else.
Here's my code:

```
lines=list()
n=int(input("Enter the a number greater than 128: "))
if n<128:
        print("ENTER A NUMBER GREATER THAN 128!!!!")
else:
    i=5
    m=5
for i in range(m):
    if n%2==0:
        n=n/2
        line=n
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        n=3*n+1
        line=n
        lines.append(line)
    print (lines)
```

Here's my output:

```
[64.0]
[64.0, 32.0]
[64.0, 32.0, 16.0]
[64.0, 32.0, 16.0, 8.0]
[64.0, 32.0, 16.0, 8.0, 4.0]
```

The only thing I want is the very last list, I don't want the first 3. How do I do this?

Comment: `print(lines)` should be outside the loop of `for i in range(m):`

Answer (score 2):

Put `print` outside the loop.
Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
lines=list()
n=int(input("Enter the a number greater than 128: "))
if n<128:
        print("ENTER A NUMBER GREATER THAN 128!!!!")
else:
    i=5
    m=5
for i in range(m):
    if n%2==0:
        n=n/2
        line=n
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        n=3*n+1
        line=n
        lines.append(line)
print (lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the list(lines) inside your 'for' loop.
So it is obvious that every time the loop will iterate your print statement will execute.
If you have to print the final list you have to keep your print outside your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

its because of your `print` function that is inside `for` loop put it out side the loop :

```
lines=list()
n=int(input("Enter the a number greater than 128: "))
if n<128:
        print("ENTER A NUMBER GREATER THAN 128!!!!")
else:
    i=5
    m=5
for i in range(m):
    if n%2==0:
        n=n/2
        line=n
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        n=3*n+1
        line=n
        lines.append(line)
print (lines)
```

---

```
>>>Enter the a number greater than 128: 128
[64, 32, 16, 8, 4]
```

or if you want to print out side the list you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) for convert indexes to `str`  and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function to concatenate str numbers with `,`  :

```
print ','.join(map(str,lines))

>>>Enter the a number greater than 128: 128
64,32,16,8,4
```